# Moving bitmap\object that is moving

Tags: android, bitmap

I had a function that moves a bitmap using two different points, one for the current position and one for the "goal" position, that way I checked if the current position x\y is smaller or bigger than the goal position and moved it towards it.

This is how I did it in code:

```
    public void fly(float x1,float y1,float scale){
    flyTo.x=(int)x1; 
    flyTo.y=(int)y1;
    mCurrentState=BossState.Flying; 
}
```

and on update:

```
    private void UpdateAll(){
switch (mCurrentState) {
case Flying:
    if(flyTo.x==position.x&&flyTo.y==position.y){
        mCurrentState=BossState.Normal;
    }
    else{
        if(flyTo.x>position.x){
            position.x+=speed;
            wiggleTo.x+=speed;
        }
        else if(flyTo.x<position.x){
            position.x-=speed;
            wiggleTo.x-=speed;
        } 
        if(flyTo.y>position.y){
            position.y+=speed;
            wiggleTo.y+=speed;
        }
        else if(flyTo.y<position.y){
            position.y-=speed;
            wiggleTo.y-=speed;
        }
    }
    break;
```

This worked perfectly, but now I made the bitmap wiggle\shake, I did that with an custom array of points and for each point I called the fly function and moved the bitmap towards to. This also worked perfectly and made the bitmap wiggle around. But here comes the problem: Connecting both the wiggle and the flying function, I want to be able to move a bitmap that is already moving around.

I tried creating another point for the wiggle, and creating its own function by doing this:

```
public void wigglefly(float x1,float y1,float scale){
    wiggleTo.x=position.x+(int)x1; 
    wiggleTo.y=position.y+(int)y1;
}
```

and on update:

```
    if(wiggleTo.x==position.x&&wiggleTo.y==position.y){
    }
    else{
        if(wiggleTo.x>position.x){
            position.x+=speed;
        }
        else if(wiggleTo.x<position.x){
            position.x-=speed;
        }
        if(wiggleTo.y>position.y){
            position.y+=speed;
        }
        else if(wiggleTo.y<position.y){
            position.y-=speed;
        }
    }
```

also for the flying I moved the wiggleTo as well,

```
case Flying:
    if(flyTo.x==position.x&&flyTo.y==position.y){
        mCurrentState=BossState.Normal;
    }
    else{
        if(flyTo.x>position.x){
            position.x+=speed;
            wiggleTo.x+=speed;
        }
        else if(flyTo.x<position.x){
            position.x-=speed;
            wiggleTo.x-=speed;
        } 
        if(flyTo.y>position.y){
            position.y+=speed;
            wiggleTo.y+=speed;
        }
        else if(flyTo.y<position.y){
            position.y-=speed;
            wiggleTo.y-=speed;
        }
    }
```

But what happens is that the bitmap is flying towards the point I call it to weirdly, and once it reaches its goal point the bitmap stops moving and doesnt wiggle\shake.

Comment: why don't you use ValueAnimator/ObjectAnimator ???

Comment: @pskink because I need to know the position of each object, for checking collision.

Comment: and you will know that,  check Animator api

Comment: @pskink should I use valueanimator or object animator? also how is that different than what I'm doing, like why would that work doing wiggle and moving and this wont?

Comment: both are good,  its up to you what you choose

Comment: @pskink are you sure I can use objectanimator? from what I see it works only on views, I'm using bitmap.. I tried finding a code for moving bitmap with objectanimator but found nothing, only for views.

Comment: yes,  i am sure,  don't try to find a code for moving bitmap, instead, write that code

Comment: @pskink just making sure its possible..

Comment: yes,  it is possible,  even easier than using ValueAnimator

Comment: @pskink But wait, from what I understand from the objectanimator class, if I tell it to move something along a path it will move it to specific points of the path, and if I move it while doing so, it will move it back to the path. I cant tell it to move a path of points while moving it somewhere else..

Comment: write some code with ObjectAnimator and see how it works...

Comment: @pskink using "ofFloat(Object target, String xPropertyName, String yPropertyName, Path path)" I tried this:  ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mob,"translationX", "translationY", pp).start(); but it gives an error.. why?

Comment: i dont know,  the error you got will explain the reason

Comment: @pskink The method ofFloat(Object, String, float...) in the type ObjectAnimator is not applicable for the arguments (Bitmap, String, String, Path) but in the document its possible http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html

Comment: so it means there is no such method with the params you passed,  see ObjectAnimator documentation

Comment: @pskink but there is, I quoted objectanimator documentation "ofFloat(Object target, String xPropertyName, String yPropertyName, Path path)" For some reason I dont have all the methods that is shown in the documentation..

Comment: it's added in api level 21, are you using api level 21+ ?

Comment: @pskink  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

Comment: so i don't know why you are getting that error

Comment: @pskink I guess ill ask a new question..

Comment: however i don't know why do you want to use that method with Path parameter... use general ofFloat method

Comment: @pskink thats even more confusing.. well I tried it but it gives me "animators may only run on looper threads" error when I run app

Comment: so why do you start it in the background thread?

Comment: @pskink well originally I wanted to make it move on the points of the circle and when it completes the circle changes shape and it goes again, so I placed the start animation where the circle changes every few seconds. Is it really necesery to use this object animator? there is no solution with moving it manually?

Comment: with ObjectAnimator you move it manually...

Comment: @pskink so why not do it the way I did it?

Comment: because wuth your solution you need a new thread, you need to manage it and call your code in fixed intervals,  using an Animator you need just to setup the Animator,  start it and respond to the propery changes,  that's all

Comment: @pskink I have a surfaceview and a thread.. I can move the bitmap with no problem, I dont know how to make it wiggle AND move at the same time.

Comment: so two different Animators would do the trick easily,  they can even manage the same property so only one setter needs to be created

Comment: @pskink Ive never used it nor understand it, Its hard for me to learn new stuff from documentation, I need examples, I need to see how people use it. I barely could find anything that contains bitmap and animators, everyone are doing it the way I did it..

Comment: did you try ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "blahBlahBlah") ?, if not, give it a try